# Obtain the permission of shutdown or restart in android

Tags: android, permissions

I am creating a shutdown/restart function.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN");  
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In xml:

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.crazyit.net"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" 
  android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
```

But it has this error in users-permission:`permission is only granted to system apps`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message explains, a normal app cannot get this permission. It would be a security risk since you could build an application that renders the phone useless.

Comment: This is true, but not very helpful.  How does one go about getting such permission? This would be useful when building COSU apps, for example.

Comment: @StephenM It requires a custom Android build containing the App as system application.

Answer (score 2):

Normal SDK applications cannot cause phones to shut down or reboot. Only applications that are part of the firmware (i.e., signed by the firmware sining key) can hold the proper permission and perform those actions.

In android SDK documents, It is clearly stated that the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` and `ACTION_REBOOT` are protected intents that can only be sent by the system". You don't have the privilege to use this intent to reboot the device for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i want to launch my app on mobile switch on and set its status on mobile switched off, So for that i use in this way

```
 <receiver android:name="WifiNotification" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and in my WifiNotification i did ::

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
   {.
    .
    .
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN))
    {.
    .
    .
    }
}
```

One of the permission is ::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the permission reference. The Android documentation for `Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` doesn't mention it for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, you can use this code for shutdown

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
```

and use this code for Reboot

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "reboot now" });
```

I use this on Xamarin.Android