# How to shut down android device programatically using Intent or PowerManager API?

Tags: android, android-powermanager

I am trying to shutdown my custom android device programatically. 
I am using the below code to do the same, but it is restarting again.I want the device to be completely shut down.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

How to achieve complete shut down i,e avoid auto restart?

Note: I have signed app with platform signatures.
Placed it in /system/app 
Added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN" />` permission in manifest.

Comment: Kindly refer this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically

Comment: @HariHaran Thanks, I'll check this.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is rooted, you can use this code for shutdown

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
```

and use this code for Reboot

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "reboot now" });
```

I use this on Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it might help.

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot" });
 p.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this

Comment: I used this, but since I am calling this from service, its asking to use intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). And if I use this flag, it just restarts.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions actually work.  You do not need to be a Device Owner app but you must have a Firmware Signed app to have the appropriate permissions. Below works for Android 8.1. It must be a Request_Shutdown without user interaction and created as a PendingIntent launched by the AlarmManager.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN"); 
            intent.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
          
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop
                            | ActivityFlags.ClearTask
                            | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            AlarmManager _alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            long milliseconds = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            _alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.Rtc, milliseconds + 5000, pendingIntent);
```