# Android/iPhone device connection via USB in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, node.js, usb

I need to connect android/iPhone device via USB with a PC. An program written in NodeJS should be able to detect the device and get information and perform some operation on the device like `reboot` and `reset`.

Anyway, I've tried some libraries like [node-usb](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb) but I'm not able to send command to the device or perform any task like that.

For iOS there's some library [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) but couldn't find any nodeJs wrapper.

Maybe I'm missing something here, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know for iOs, but I don't think it is possible in Android. The reason is with permissions: it would rather be a bug then a feature if someone could just plug in a USB and shutdown your device without asking.

So, maybe if you would ask permissions for access and such, maybe.

Android App with [Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically) is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone).

And that is with Apps, not with NodeJS, it's not native to either iOs or Android.