# Reboot programmatically Android Things

Tags: java, runtime.exec, android-things

I want to use this code in order to reboot my *RPI3* running *Android Things*:

```
public static void Reboot()
{
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied

I add to the manifest all the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: not the android permission mater, but the linux `su` command permission. make sure you process(user) have the permission to execute su

Comment: How can I check if I can execute "su"?

Comment: that is a basic linux problem, can not say much here. please learn how to execute command in linux bash, and check binary executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/system/bin/reboot` binary in *DP 4*, so as in all the previous dev previews, has world-executable permission, i.e. the following yields

```
adb shell ls -l /system/bin | grep reboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root shell   ... reboot
```

That said, it is yet possible to execute the binary for any user (a.k.a app process in *Android*) without a need to grab `su`. Just execute in *Java* for

**rebooting**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");
```

or for **powering off**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot -p");
```

**No permission**'s needed in `AndroidManifest.xml` to run the binary successfully.

*Caution: in case of security model changes in newer OS versions this approach may not work.*

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reboot");` works at the first time. Thank you. As mentioned in the comment at @Devunwired I need only to execute AVRdude with su

Comment: _"'su' command are not accessible in any case?"_ You could try `adb root`, then `adb remount` (to prevent `/system/ not in /proc/mounts`), then `adb shell chmod 777 /system/xbin/su` (777 is just an example, you might pick a more restricted mode), **but you know that making `su` world-executable is a huge security hole, right?** :)

Answer (score 7):

You can now do a reboot using:

https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/devicemanagement/DeviceManager.html

Example

```
 public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

     void doReboot() {
         DeviceManager.getInstance().reboot();
     }

     void doFactoryReset() {
         boolean wipeExternalCard = true;
         DeviceManager.getInstance().factoryReset(wipeExternalCard);
     }
  }
```

You need the `com.google.android.things.permission.REBOOT` permission

Answer (score 3):

Access to system-protected features (such as those provided by the `PowerManager.reboot()` API) will be available to apps running on Android Things in a future developer preview release. You cannot (and should not) attempt to run your app process as the root user via `su`.

As a side note, the developer images for Android Things are built as `userdebug`, which means you can access root from the shell by simply rebooting the ADB daemon with the `adb root` command before you attempt to access the shell. This gives you any root access you may need during development without compromising the device security and allowing app processes to run as root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I will wait for the future release! 

"su" command are not accessible in any case? e.g. if I need to run AVRDude (to upload an arduino firmware... ) how can I do that without "su"?

Comment: The recommended method would be to implement the protocol directly using the Peripheral I/O APIs, rather than calling out to an external executable that requires elevated permissions. This is a difficult thing for us to secure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! At the end the method suggested by @Onik is able to reboot the RPI3. Now I need to find a way to execute AVRdude :D

Answer (score 0):

You need a root access.

```
public static void runCmd(String cmd) {
    DataOutputStream os;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can run any commands that require root access like this: `runCmd("reboot");`

Comment: ok so my question is... how to get root access in Android Things?