# Restart RPI 3 Model B Andoid Things remotely

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I want to restart my raspberry pi 3 model B remotely. I am running Android Things OS on RPi.
Can anyone tell how can I do this?

Comment: [Powering off Android Things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41503899/3290339). Basically, the command is `adb shell reboot`.

Comment: Yes. But how can I use this remotely using Android things?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own remote service provider to send commands through the device such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). Then, you can use the [DeviceManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/DeviceManager) API on Android Things with the [reboot method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/DeviceManager.html#reboot()).

```
DeviceManager deviceManager = DeviceManager.getInstance();
deviceManager.reboot();
```

Make sure you set the permission in your manifest too.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidthings.updatemanagersample">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.REBOOT" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Will this work remotely? If yes then how will I identify that which one RPI has to be restarted. I mean how will I recognise?

Comment: This is what your app will need to run. You will have to figure out device registration and management for yourself.