# What code would I use to turn phone completely off at the end of timer?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, cross-platform

Main Concise Question: ***What code would you use to turn the phone completely off? What would that code look like?***

*Question explanation:* I am trying to build a simple cross platform mobile app in visual studio for mac (using xamarin and writing it in C#). Its a simple timer app that turns the phone completely off when the timer has counted down. An ultimate sleep timer if you will. The timer part is super easy but I've never seen or learned any code that could be used to turn the phone completely off when the timer ends.

*Experience level*: I'm pretty good with C# & visual studio on windows. Still trying to get used to Visual Studio for mac and xamarin, but I got an 85% on an intermediate C# course at my local college. So I know I still have a lot to learn

Comment: You can't.  There are no public APIs that would allow this.  It would be a horrible UX and security issue if apps were allowed to shutdown the device without any user interaction.

Comment: There are platform-specific methods available, e.g. [on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically) but you need a rooted device or a system-level application. So in practice, as Jason said, you can't.