# How to switch off Android phone by programmitically in android

Tags: android

I am getting a problem to switch off my mobile phone though programmitically in android.can you help me to find  solution of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693682/turn-off-device-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Works on 4.0 and above!

```
        Intent i = new 
        Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
        i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
```

and put this permission on manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN" />`

Alternative solution: **For Rooted device**

*Shutdown:*

```
try {
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
proc.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

*Restart:*

Same code, just use `reboot` instead of `reboot -p`.

Comment: This way is not working in my MI redmi 4 device,  when I execute this code activity opens and close at the time. I checked all permission and Android Version but this is not working.

Comment: If you use first approach then you need access as a Super user. and If you go for 2nd solution, it should work fine. @MohitVarma

Comment: how can I get super user permission to do this task easily ?