# what is the shutdown code in the android studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, system-shutdown

i'm writting a application,one function of which is shutting down the phone.so what should i write in the android studio now?
i found the code segment in the net.but it did not build normally

> what added in the **MainActivity.kt**

```
fun shutdown(){
        val intent:Intent = Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN")
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM",true)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

> what added in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.dotzhang.toolbox"
          android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/></maniest>
```

> **error information**

```
01/11 16:38:46: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 30.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

List of apks:
[0] 'D:\javaproj\toolbox\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.dotzhang.toolbox tried to change user null'
Retry
```

> here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.dotzhang.toolbox"
          android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Toolbox">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="toolbox">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: check out this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700240`

Comment: ok,now i know that there is no permission of `SHUTDOWN` in the non-system app.However there is no solution in the question mentioned above.

Comment: Can you share complete `AndroidMaifest.xml` file

Comment: ok, i'll post the xml file in my answer