# FLUTTER -Turn on and Turn off your device

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to schedule the time to turn on your phone from flutter app on android and ios?

Answer (score 0):

In Android there is a way to bring up the shutdown dialog as mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700240/3825725). However, iOS apps have no way of achieving this as the only way to perform a shutdown is through physically holding down the power button for about 10 seconds and sliding a slider to the left.

So to answer your question: no, you cannot do that across platforms.