# Is there a way to reload the device from the chrome console in React Native so I don't have to constantly shake it?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

It's easy in the simulator--you just press command+R.

But on the phone, you have to constantly shake it, and that really disturbs your workflow, especially when for like the first time in history everything live-codes beautifully.

What's the easiest way to reload my app without shaking it? Stopping and playing and Xcode is worse--so that's not an option. I would like to do the closest thing to command+R but for the device instead of the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround for now using adb shell:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.app_name && adb shell am start -n com.app_name/com.app_name.MainActivity
```

u can optimize that by using the `restart` shell command, but that has [security restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065842/obtain-the-permission-of-shutdown-or-restart-in-android) you'll need to work through.

I might look later into the react-native way of doing that.

Hope this helps.