# How to Shutdown android device in C# Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, shutdown

I have tried shutdown with this

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "shutdown" });
```

and this

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
i.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true);
StartActivity(i);
```

Comment: Have you added the permissions in manifest file?

Comment: This would have to be installed as a system app or you would need a rooted phone.

Comment: My phone is rooted

Comment: I'm using this permission in manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's all, i have read in another post

i use this for shutdown imediatly

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that Runtime.getRuntime() works only on Rooted devices.

The second code would work but not in all cases. You might want to add Shutdown permission which you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065842/obtain-the-permission-of-shutdown-or-restart-in-android/14065879#14065879). Again for this case, a normal app cannot request for this permission and you need to be a system-level app.

Comment: Thank's but my device is rooted. I will try add Shutdown permission on my application.

Comment: In Xamarin i need to use [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionShutdown })] this for permission

Answer (score 0):

If your device does not have SU installed but your app is signed with the firmware signing certificate you can use this to power off without user interaction.
None of these solutions above actually work for me.  You do not need to be a Device Owner app but you must have a Firmware Signed app to have the appropriate permissions. Below works for Android 8.1. It must be a Request_Shutdown without user interaction and created as a PendingIntent launched by the AlarmManager. In your AndroidManifest.xml you must have DEVICE_POWER, SHUTDOWN and REQUEST_SHUTDOWN permissions.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN"); 
            intent.PutExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
          
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop
                            | ActivityFlags.ClearTask
                            | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            AlarmManager _alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            long milliseconds = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            _alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.Rtc, milliseconds + 5000, pendingIntent);
```